# How to apply different functions based on the dataframe index row

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apply

Image a have a complex function defined as:

```
def func(year):
 match year:
  case 2023:
   do_some()
  case _:
   do_other()
```

Now I want to apply this function based on the row index (a Pandas DateTimeIndex) of the DataFrame `df`, e.g.

```
df.index # contains [2023, 2024, ..., 2030]
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What kind of functions? What are the arguments of `do_some()` and `do_other()`?

Comment: the take the value of the row and some parameters (that depends on the year, I'm thinking about reading this from a TOML file as they could be customize), i.e. I want to use something like df['new_col'] = df['my_col'].apply(...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mapping dict:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (10, 2)),
                  columns=list('AB'),
                   index=np.random.randint(2023,2025, 10))

def do_some(df):
    return df['A'] / 2
    
def do_other(df):
    return df['B'] * 2
    
funcs = {2023: do_some}
default = do_other

df['C'] = (df.reset_index()  # you need unique index
             .groupby('index', group_keys=False)
             .apply(lambda x: funcs.get(x.name, do_other)(x))
             .sort_index().to_numpy())
```

Output:

```
>>> df
      A  B     C
2023  5  2   2.5  # do_some,  A / 2
2024  3  5  10.0  # do_other, B * 2
2023  1  3   0.5
2023  9  6   4.5
2023  8  4   4.0
2024  2  6  12.0
2023  6  1   3.0
2023  6  1   3.0
2024  7  5  10.0
2023  4  8   2.0
```